# Setting the generated source directory for annotation processors in Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, annotation-processing

I'm trying to move a build which generates sources using an annotation processor to Maven. I've tried configuring the maven-compiler-plugin as follows:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerArgument>-s ${project.build.directory}/target/generated-sources/annotation-processing</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

But javac fails with

```
[INFO] Compilation failure  
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid flag: -s /home/robert/workspaces/betbrain/sportsengine.common/sportsengine.bean.test/target/target/generated-sources/annotation-processing  
Usage: javac <options> <source files>  
use -help for a list of possible options
```

As far as I can tell, -s should be passed before the source files to javac, but maven passes it after.

How can I pass the `-s` flag properly to the maven-compiler-plugin?

---

*Update*: the [maven-annotation-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) does not seem to work.

When configured as

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${generated.sources.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>xxx.annotation.EnforceJavaBeansConventionsProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Execution fails with

```
[INFO] [processor:process {execution: process}]
error: Annotation processor 'xxx.annotation.EnforceJavaBeansConventionsProcessor' not found
1 error
```

Comment: Thanks to mentioning maven-annotation-plugin. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin was using the harcoded Windows classpath separator to build the classpath, so it was failing on my Linux machine.

Submitted patches:

- [system dependent path separator character](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/detail?id=1)
- [Allow the default processor discovery mechanism to run](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/issues/detail?id=6)

Answer (score 5):

I may be missing something but shouldn't you:

1. Generate sources in `target/generated-sources/annotation-processing` during the `generate-sources` phase? The [apt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/) or the [maven-annotation-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) could help.
2. Include generated sources when compiling sources into `target/classes` using `<includes>` in the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) or the [maven-build-helper-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html)?

**EDIT:** Where is `xxx.annotation.EnforceJavaBeansConventionsProcessor` located? Don't you need to add `dependencies` to the configuration of the maven-annotation-plugin as documented on the [Usage](http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/docs/usage.html) page?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>process</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory><!-- PROCESSOR OUT DIR --> 
        <processors><!-- LIST OF PROCESSOR CLASS(S) -->
          <processor>org.bsc.apt.BeanInfoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </processors>
      </configuration> 
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies/><!-- ADD DEPENDENCIES HERE IF REQUIRED -->
</plugin>
```

PS: I wouldn't use `src/main/generated` as output directory but rather a subdirectory of `target/generated-sources`.

Comment: Yes, I should. How should I perform step 1?

Comment: Do you use the maven-apt-plugin or the maven-annotation-plugin?

Comment: I am now investigating the maven-annotation-plugin - since I'm using the Java 6 APIs, but apparently I'm required to list the processor I'm using, and I can't pass those in properly. Is it possible to bind the maven-compiler-plugin to the generate-sources phase?

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but of interest:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-75

I'm afraid there are a number of issues using JSR 269 in Maven, at least with the default compiler plugin.

Comment: With maven-compiler-plugin 2.2, you should not need to do anything to get 269 to discover default processors.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this could be that $JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk 1.5 version instead of 1.6. (on windows check %JAVA_HOME% of course)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with GWTP Source Generate APT Processing annotations

It was because I didn't set a version for the compiler plugin, my final setup:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <!-- <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument> -->
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>${generated.sources}</generatedSourcesDirectory>
        <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.processor.GenEventProcessor</annotationProcessor>
            <annotationProcessor>com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.processor.GenDtoProcessor</annotationProcessor>
            <annotationProcessor>com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.processor.GenDispatchProcessor</annotationProcessor>
        </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem ...

---

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:

javac: invalid flag: -s
...
```

---

***Are you using java*** 5 ?

```
$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)

Java version: 1.5.0_22

Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.22/jre

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-24-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ ll /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*

$ ll /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/jre/bin/java*
```

---

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java



$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)

Java version: 1.6.0_24

Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre

Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-24-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

---

now, *mvn install* should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the `maven-processor-plugin` as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process-my-annotations</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <processors>
            <processor>x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor</processor>
          </processors>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</outputDirectory>
          <outputClassDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</outputClassDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The generated code goes into *target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations*, and generated resources into *target/test-classes* (the default for the **process** goal is *target/generated-sources* and *target/classes*, respectively).

I also need to use `maven-build-helper-plugin` to add *target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations* to the test source path so that **test-compile** phase will compile the generated code.